# Screen does not turn back on after turning off for inactivity

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

If my screen turns off due to inactivity, it will not come back on. It *does* turn on when waking up from suspend.

I have 16.04 on a HP Compaq nc6000.

In System Settings -> Details, the graphics line says "`Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV350`".

The relevant line in `lspci`:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV350/M10 / RV366660/M11 [Mobility Radeon 9600 (Pro) / 9700]`

Right now my workaround is to set "Turn screen off when inactive for: Never" but I'd like a better workaround or fix. Any ideas? All suggestions are welcome.

Edit: As a workaround I've given up on Unity and installed GNOME 3.